# Angular routing first, mvc routing otherwise

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I have an application using Angular and node.js (running on IIS 7.5) for the UI, and then a .NET Web API for all the endpoint calls.

Angular routing is working as expected, and API routing is working as expected...when running the API through Visual Studio/IIS Express and `ng serve` to fire up the UI. Of course, they're running on two separate ports.

The goal is to deploy to a single IIS Web Site and, unfortunately, a single Application Pool.

Given the URL of http://www.mycoolapplication.com for the UI and http://www.mycoolapplication.com/api for the API, how to I get Angular to ignore routing for anything matching `api` and all of `api`'s children?

I'm going through the `Routes` module, and would love to be able to add something to a `path` object, but there doesn't appear to be anything to accomplish *excluding* something from the Angular routing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this `web.config` in your frontend app (the folder with index.html). It will handle all requests except api/*.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="API Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(api)(.*)$" />
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, @maxim Thanks for the help. For some reason, I didn't think the web.config would come into play for the routing in this scenario. The configuration must be processing the `rewrite` rules in order since the API Rule is "before" the Angular rule, which I already had in my web.config.